# Railway Golang Deployment Issue

Tags: go, microservices, grpc, grpc-go

I made the microservices using grpc in golang.

But when i tried to deploy it in railway . The gateway is not able to make connection to tcp microservice ?

Here are the screenshots :

It says Time out  Issue (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HerKQ.png)

Here are the both code of gateway and location service (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NflF2.png)

the start command of gateway is

`./gateway/out -location_addr=mapuptask-production.up.railway.app:8040`

Comment: Please don't include images when the content (in this case, the source code) would be more useful. Images may not outlive the question and it's not easy for readers to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You assume familiarity with Railway. Is it [Railway](https://railway.app/)? Are you confident that Railway supports gRPC? Specifically http/2 required by gRPC?

Comment: Does your code run locally? You reference various ports. 8040 does not appear to be published for `mapuptask-production.up.railway.app` but the Railway (?) proxy appears to be listening on 443. Commonly, cloud-based services are proxied through a secure port like 443 but I'm unable to query a gRPC service at this port either.

Comment: So , If i don't want to run it on kubernetes.  Can you suggest. On which I can deploy it ?